# Do I need layout/activity_main in react native app (android) for admob?

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I've created a react native app and trying to add some ads following admob doc and when I add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in `MainActivity.java` in Android Studio it gives me this error: 'cannot resolve symbol activity_main'.

I don't have a layout folder in res (have re-created the app and still nothing).

Do I need to create layout and add activity_main.xml to it? And in that case, what do I add to the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

No

You don't have to touch the native code of android of react native only for exceptional cases.
Follow an online tutorial to do the work.
How add [How add addmob with react native](https://enappd.com/blog/implement-admob-in-react-native-with-firebase/133/#:%7E:text=Click%20Apps%20in%20the%20sidebar,in%20your%20React%20Native%20app.) on google

Comment: I followed this guide and when I rebuild the app (successful in terminal) but when I `npx react-native run-android` the app just crash in Android Studio.

Comment: I get this in terminal `ReactNativeFirebase WARNING: NPM package '@react-native-firebase/admob' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v11.5.0 but found v14.3.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.` Do all react-native-firebase dependencies need to be the same version?

Comment: Fixed this  But also have this message `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.`